# How to test get method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I was trying to test a get method of a `flask-restful api`. I am facing issue in testing that api.

API is:

```
class SomeClass(Resource):
    @login_required
    def get(self, some_id):

        print some_id

        """
        some function in this api
        """
```

It is registered as

```
api.add_resource(SomeClass, '/v1/some_exp/<some_id>')
```

I am trying to write test case for `get method` of `some_class`.

Test case is

```
def test_get_method(self):
    rv = self.client.get('/v1/some_exp/1')
    assert rv.status == '200 OK'
```

When I ran this test-case, I observed that `get` method is getting called but the value of `some_id` in `get` method is not coming out as `1` but some other random number. Now, I am not getting this unusual behaviour.

I am new to python and testing api for the first time. Any useful suggestion will be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: What does “some other random number” look like? Is it always the same one?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, It was same, 163

Comment: And if you remove the `print`, no numbers show up?

Comment: Did you search for that number, 163, in your all of your codebase? That's a *very specific number*.

Comment: @ryan: Yes,  after removing print, no number show up

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, I searched that number in my codebase as well as in the database associated with my this app. This number/id is not there even.

Comment: Then I suggest you use a debugger; `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before that line. It'll be a bit painful to have to step through all the layers, but that'll give you the definitive answer as to where that number comes from.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, I will try that way of debugging it. Will come back to you if, I will get more clear error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I figured out the error. Actually, that api requires login, & it was decorated with login_required decorator. I was not sending the headers from login into this. I am updating the question now. It is now solved. 
Thanks

Comment: But, I am still not sure why it was getting called, without passing headers of login!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error. Actually that API was decorated with `@login_required` decorator & I was not sending required headers related to login.

I updated the test as:

```
def login(self, username, password):
    return self.client.post(url_for('security.login'), data=dict(
        email=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=False)


def test_get_method(self):
    response = self.login('test@gmail.com', 'password')
    rv = self.client.get('/v1/some_exp/1', headers=response.headers)
    assert rv.status == '200 OK'
```

After doing this, test case is running just fine.

Thanks!!